# Subtract two dates in different documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, kibana

I have two documents in elasticsearch with the same date field i.e:

```
{"event":"event1", "datetime":"2017-04-10T12:41:30"}

{"event":"event2", "datetime":"2017-04-10T12:41:35"}
```

I would like to get the difference between the datetime of these two events. I took a look at script fields but it allows me to perform operations only on the same documento, not in two different documents.

Does anybody know how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way to do it in Elasticsearch. Pull both of these fields to your application and apply the logic.